# Swift Package Compiler Issue

Tags: swift, package-managers, swift-package-manager

I have a Project has 4 Swift Package Dependencies. Package A, B, C, D. Each package uses the previous packages as dependencies.

I'm facing an issue where Package D is having issues compiling due to do errors inside Package B that don't actually exist. `(Cannot find type 'CustomType' in scope)` As Package B and the xcode project I'm using the packages in both work fine.

This is preventing me from working efficiently because the complier wont work inside Package D.

I've tried deleting derived data, cleaning the build folder, reseting package cache and none of this has worked. I'm assuming I'm doing something wrong, but I have no idea what it is.

```
let package = Package(
    name: "PackageD",
    defaultLocalization: "en",
    platforms: [
        .iOS(.v13),
        .macOS(.v10_15)
    ],
    products: [
        .library(
            name: "PackageD",
            targets: ["PackageD"]),
    ],
    dependencies: [
        .package(url: "PackageA", "0.0.1"..<"1.0.0"),
        .package(url: "PackageB", "0.0.1"..<"1.0.0"),
        .package(url: "PackageC", "0.0.1"..<"1.0.0"),
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "PackageD",
            dependencies: [
                "PackageA",
                "PackageB",
                "PackageC"
            ],
            resources: [.process("Resources")]
        ),
    ]
)
```

Comment: Can you expand more on the error that 'B' is experiencing? If a dependency fails to compile, your package will not compile.

Comment: Package B only has issues with the complier recognizing custom objects/Types when it's being used inside Package D. Example: Inside Package D: `Cannot find type 'CustomStructFromPackageB' in scope`

Comment: Two initial thoughts... 1) Verify that `CustomStructFromPackageB` is declared as `Public` 2) Verify that `import PackageB` is declared in the file referencing the struct.

Comment: 1) Verified 2) That's not the issue. The issue is inside Package D, Package B can not find it's own `CustomStructFromPackageB` in scope. - Package B also works just fine on it's own, in Package C, and in the xcode project.

Comment: Without further specifics (Other package descriptions, code specifics) it might be impossible to troubleshoot this.

Comment: Thank you for your help so far. If you're willing to help, I'm more than happy to share more. I was just trying to keep it as simple as possible. - To me, it really seems like a compiler issue with Package D issue. Since Package B has no issues anywhere else.

Comment: Sure! I'd be happy to help if I can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there were a few different structs that required the use of UIKit. Which mean that UIKit needed to be able to be imported. Which wasn't an issue in the xcode project, but was an issue in the package that was built upon other packages.

Adding `#if canImport(UIKit)` and `#endif` to all the files that required it solved the issue.